# Python - slow matrix performance

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm trying to perform some exact diagonalization on a 2^N*2^N complex matrix, with N being up to 16.
I use numpy.linalg.eigh and use the eigenvector matrix to perform a scalar product to create a new 2^N*2^N matrix.
This new matrix should be 64gb(=(2^2N)*16), but using htop I can that python consumes 261gb. The main problem is that creating this matrix takes very long time, unproportional to the amount of time it takes to perform the same computation for N=14,12 (where this should scale as dim^2).

Has anybody encountered such problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd start with, e.g., N=5 and do the matrix diagonalization. Measure the computing time and slowly increase N. Since the diagonalization has cubic(!) complexity O(N^3), I guess it's computationally infeasible. (And thus you won't need to worry about memory...)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The diagonalization is indeed cubic, but the problem is not with that but with the construction of a new matrix using the scalar product (this should scale quadratically).

Comment: Could you show your code please?

Comment: When a `numpy` operation starts to bog down, I usually assume it's doing an excessive amount of memory swapping.  But then I'm using an older computer with a finite amount of RAM.